# Reactjs Typerscript: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-tsx

Im trying to filter data with multiple key value in reactjs with tsx. **Cards.tsx** is a parent component and **ShipmentCard.tsx** is a child. I'm getting `Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'never'` error. I just want to return the related object based on search criteria. Can anyone let me know where I made a mistake?

**Cards.tsx**

```js
class Cards extends Component {
  state = {
    card: [],
    filter: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadShipmentList();
  }

  handleChange = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({ filter: event.target.value });
  };

  loadShipmentList() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/shipments")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ card: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const { card, filter } = this.state;
    const lowercasedFilter = filter.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = this.state.card.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
      );
    });

    return (
        <Card className="Search-Bar">
          <CardContent>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <TextField
                  label="Search"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {filteredData.map((card: any) => (
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <ShipmentCard key={card.id} value={card} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

**db.json**

```js
{
  "shipments": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Heromisha",
      "total": "1000",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "userId": "E222"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "Honda",
      "total": "3000",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "userId": "E111"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When does this error occur, upon startup? Also, I would suggest not using the word 'filter' for your variable.

Comment: noted that. when start typing. `TypeError: item[key].toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: @rrd - There's no reason you can't use `filter` as a variable name.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for coming back. I'm still figuring on it. `item[key].toLowerCase()` object value and `filter.toLowerCase()` is input value. This is error that im getting `TypeError: item[key].toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: @SKL - You won't get that error if you do what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Last approach thrown this error `Binding element 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type`

Answer (score 2):

`Component` is a generic interface with two type parameters: The type of your props, and the type of your state. Your component doesn't seem to have props so you can just use `object` or `{}` for the props interface, but you do have state, so you need to say what *shape* that state has:

```
interface Card {
  id:     string;
  name:   string;
  total:  string;
  status: string;
  userId: string;
}
interface CardsState {
  card:   Card[];
  filter: string;
}
class Cards extends Component<object,CardsState> {
  state: CardsState = {
    card: [],
    filter: ""
  };
  // ...
}
```

---

Separately, the next couple of problems I suspect you'll have are:

1. You're not checking that `fetch` succeeded. You're not alone in this, it's a **very** common error (so common I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog). You need to add a check to your `fetch` call:

   ```
   fetch("http://localhost:3001/shipments")
   .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok) {
       throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
     }
     return response.json();
   })
   // ...
   ```
2. You're not handling errors from `fetch`. `loadShipmentList` should either return the promise chain (and then `componentDidMount` and other places it's used would handle errors) or handle/report errors itself.
3. You're setting `card` to the result of parsing your JSON. Your code assumes `card` is an array, but the JSON's top level isn't an array, it's an object with a `shipments` property (which is an array). I suspect you meant to set `card` (which should be `cards`, plural, or `shipments`) to the `shipments` property of the returned data:

   ```
   .then(({shipments}) => this.setState({ card: shipments }));
   //    ^^         ^^                          ^^^^^^^^^
   ```

There may be further issues, but the main answer above should address the `never` issue, and hopefully these further hints have helped.

---

In a comment you've said that when you give `card` a type, this code causes an error:

```
const filteredData = this.state.card.filter(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
    item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
  );
});
```

If you expect the shape of the data in the JSON to be variable, you could declare `card` as `any[]` (or perhaps `Record<string,string>[]`) and then that dynamic code would work. But only if you want the component driven by the JSON. Otherwise, update the code to use the typesafe property names:

```
const filteredData = this.state.card.filter(({id, name, total, status, userId}) =>
  `${id}\t${name}\t${total}\t${status}\t${userId}`.toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
);
```

Comment: im quite confused with your third point. When i start typing `TypeError: item[key].toLowerCase is not a function` error thrown

Comment: @SKL - I'm not sure how that relates to my third point, but if you want to access the properties on entries in `card` dynamically like that, you'll have to tell TypeScript you want to do that. This is a fairly basic TypeScript thing, nothing to do with React, and getting a bit far afield of the original question. I've added a bit to the end of the answer about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't real type of state.card[...], becouse it's declared as array.
The most simple way is to declare this as any[]

```
  state = {
    card: [] as any[],
    filter: ""
  };
```

Or describe data type explicit

```
interface Card {
    "id": string,
    "name": string,
    "total": string,
    "status": string,
    "userId": string
}
...
      state = {
        card: [] as Card[],
        filter: ""
      };
```

Or by object example

```
const cardSample = {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Heromisha",
      "total": "1000",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "userId": "E222"
  };

type Card = typeof cardSample;

    ...
          state = {
            card: [] as Card[],
            filter: ""
          };
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've checked the code in the playground and it is compiled well

Comment: I checked in playground without React typing. Now I've cheked it in local project that created by react-create-app, and the changes fix the error "Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'never'".

Comment: [Without fix ](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCcAmMCmAPALqgdiuA9gLYAOBOum0A3gFDTQSZjbQC8N9D0wiSAXNADaAXQA0XBgDMAliGwJBAIiVcAvgG5a9BLiSoEACgCUnbj3JMaPPmOiz5B6GvbRMACxkQAdExaotc2BLKhACAHcDXghUJAAxOQVXBwVvTAIAGQiDeBiTQO5gnCsUg1iAERYwVw8vX2Zsb15kb1KjGWwidgA+M3NoXUwAVwQcaAB5ACMAK1RgTG8Aa1QATwhDDtQiY19iVENllZ7Jfs2iIUORNMzshFz9nZkcUCH9dbDIhGjYhMcEYxODGMBQYamB2nMgxGYwA5DD1LQ1NoMGQEFR9FIwEN5HA+BANEA)

Comment: With fix https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCcAmMCmAPALqgdiuA9gLYAOBOum0A3gFDTQSZjbQC8N9D0wiSAXNADaAXWiRxOAJ6iANFwYAzAJYhsCQQCJNXAL4BuWvQS4kqBAAoAlJ249yTGjz6zoKteei720TAAtlCAA6JhZUQztgByoQAgB3c14IVCQAMVV1H3d1IMwCABl483hk6wjuKJxHbPMUgBEWMB9-QJDmbCDeZCCay2VsInYAPls7aBNMAFcEHGgAeQAjACtUYEwggGtUKQgLftQiKxDiVAstqWGFMf2iIXORXIKihBLTo+UcUEmzXdiEhCSKXSHgQViuDCs5QYukhRjsE2mswA5Ei9LRdEYMGQEFQzIowJM1HA+BB9EA

Comment: Nice! Ah, we're talking about different calls to `toUpperCase`! :-) That explains it.